# What URL parameter do you pass to use PageView by default in an embedded Power BI report?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I found the following documentation for URL parameters:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/report-builder-url-parameters

I am trying to display the report in "PageView" when it opens instead of the "Default" view.  The documentation states it is the following parameter with the following value

> **rdl:reportView**
>
> - 'interactive' (default): load the report in interactive mode.
> - 'pageView': load the report in page view mode.

But this does not work and the report always displays in default mode.  I have tried various permutations of parameter names (e.g. rdl:reportView, rdl:view, reportView, view, etc) and with various values pageView, 'pageView', 'page', without success.

The documentation also incorrectly lists **rdl:parameterPanelState** as the parameter for not displaying the parameter panel but the parameter is actually **rdl:parameterPanel** so there appear to be some issues with the documentation.

Any ideas on how to default to Page view? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue.

The correct way of passing URL parameters for Paginated report is as follows:
https://app.powerbi.com/groups/your_dedicated_capacity_workspace_id/rdlreports/your_paginated_report_id?rdl:reportView=pageView&rdl:parameterPanel=hidden

e.g.,
[image: example]